# Using COPY --from overwrites the binaries in my container

Tags: docker

I have a very simple Docker image that should contain both NodeJS and OpenJDK (to build Cordova apps).

So far so good, all works well, the versions are correct and the command line knows all the binaries.

But when I use a multi-stage build, the last image from Alpine is unable to find the APK command (the package manager), and I need it.

My current Dockerfile is

```
FROM node:current-slim AS node
COPY --from=openjdk:latest . .

FROM alpine:latest

COPY --from=node . . 

ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/openjdk-14

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm i -g @angular/cli cordova

CMD ["bash"]
```

When I try to run

```
apk add unzip
```

The error `bash: apk: command not found` pops up.

Running

```
docker run -it --rm alpine:latest
```

Allows me to use APK.

It seems the binaries are overriden and I cannot use them anymore.

Is there a way of doing this ? (I'm quite new to Docker)

My requirements are for the following commands to work without any error when running `docker run -it --rm --name myContainer myImage` :

```
npm -v
node -v
java -version
apk --help
```

Comment: Those `COPY` instructions are trying to copy the entire filesystem – binaries, libraries, `/etc` config files, everything – from one image to another, and that just won't work well.  You can't really merge Docker images at all.  Can you just use `apk add` to install Node and a JDK into the Alpine image?

Comment: @DavidMaze bingo. The filesystem being overwritten is what's going on here. Using `apk` to install NodeJS and a JDK is what I would do

Comment: Thank you for the information, I was under the impression that it would copy the files without overriding them, which apparently is wrong. I will try to create a single image from alpine directly as suggested and see how it works out for me !